# Product carousel on my site is showing up blank in Google's fetch and render for mobile

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, links, fetch-as-google, render

Using GSC, I am trying to fetch a page with products and content, this page also has few products in carousel format and when I render this page for desktop or mobile, I am seeing everything fine but products in carousel shows up blank (for how Google sees your page).

What does that mean? Is Google not able to crawl those links? If not, then why not? I am not very good at understanding if these are JavaScript links or something else is happening.